# Webview atualizando página URL quando giro a tela

Tags: android, webview

Estou fazendo um teste no webview e está ok. Porém quando giro o smartphone ele atualiza a url da minha página. Gostaria de manter a rotação sem essa atualização, mantendo ele na tela que o está da url.

Alguma dica?

Answer (score 0):

Bom consegui aqui. Quem tiver o mesmo problema no XML do webview, acrescentar

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
```

E no `Manifest` , na Activity do Webview acrescentar também

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
```

Comment: Mas nesse caso, ao girar o dispositivo, a tela não gira.

Comment: @ramaral aqui girou no smartphone. Testei no físico direto

Comment: Tem razão. O que queria dizer é que se tiver layouts para *landscape* e *portrait, resources* por idioma e outros tipos de configuração eles não são automaticamente aplicados. Essa abordagem resolve esse problema mas cria muitos outros.

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece porque quando o dispositivo é rodado a Activity onde está a WebView é destruída e recriada, fazendo que o método `oncreate()` seja chamado.

Faça o *override* do método `onSaveInstanceState` e guarde o Url que a WebView está a mostrar.

Mais tarde, quando a Activity for recriada, poderá obter o Url do *Bundle* passado ao método `onCreate()`.

Será qualquer coisa do género:

```
private String mUrl;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Verifica se a Activity foi recreada.
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Recupera a Url
        mUrl = savedInstanceState.getString("Url");
    } else {
        mUrl = "valor default da url";
    }
    ...
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    bundle.putString("Url", suaWebView.getUrl());

}
```